# Tomcat issue with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat7, nas

I'm totally new in Spring Boot with Java and Linux Environment.
I have developped with Visual Studio Code a small API which is running perfectly on my PC.
Now I have my war file ready to deploy on a Synology NAS with TOMCAT 7.0.92 installed.

But when I deploy on the NAS I have this issue :

`org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accountapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT]`

I have made several test with a simple "Hello Word" and it's the same.

When I create the projet I'm using "spring-boot-blank-archetype" version 1.0.6, in my pom file I have

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>``
```

I think about the Tomcat version but as I see 1.2.7 for the release of spring (if it's the version of course) I'm sure of anything. Or the web.xml file (but another try without spring is working without this file)...

Could you help me in identifying the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Ok, I understood.
The jar file of the app already embeds a Tomcat Server.
In fact, I have to run the jar file on the NAS, that's it...